# using != in while statements

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax

```
gender = input("Gender: ")
while gender.capitalize() != "M" or gender.capitalize() != "F":
    print("Only M or F please: ")
    gender = (input("Gender: "))
```

I have also tried

```
gender = input("Gender: ")
while not gender.capitalize() == "M" or gender.capitalize() == "F":
    print("Only M or F please: ")
    gender = (input("Gender: "))
```

the code works as expected when its == and is not != or while not

Comment: What are you expecting, and what is happening instead?

Comment: The `or` should be an `and`. English doesn't translate well to code as the boolean logic in english is quite weird.

Comment: The gender variable is always either not equal to M or not equal to F. If it's M, that's not equal to F. If it's F, that's not equal to M.

Comment: You missed second `not`: `while not gender.capitalize() == "M" or not gender.capitalize() == "F":`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `and` not `or` as the lastest will always be `True` (if you input `M` then it's not `F` and conversely):

```
gender = input("Gender: ")
while gender.capitalize() != "M" and gender.capitalize() != "F":
    print("Only M or F please: ")
    gender = input("Gender: ")
```

Or use `not in`:

```
gender = input("Gender: ")
while gender.capitalize() not in ["M", "F"]:
    print("Only M or F please: ")
    gender = input("Gender: ")
```